# Match all tickets on a particular day

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

A continuation of the question found here: [How to write dynamic Linq to count matching numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25694403/how-to-write-dynamic-linq-to-count-matching-numbers)

I have two tables here which I'm querying for matching numbers. One ticket has many ticket numbers.

```
Ticket:
TicketId, Name, AddDateTime

TicketNumbers:
Id, TicketId, Number
```

Currently I have this function which gets the match count I want. It's pretty cryptic to me - I don't know how someone would read out this Linq in plain english.

```
public int CountPartialMatchingTicket(IList<int> numbers)
{
    var arr = numbers.ToArray();
    int count = db.Tickets.Count(
        tk=>arr.All(n=> tk.TicketNumbers.Any(tn=>tn.Number== n)));
    return count;
}
```

However, the Linq above is matching the ticket numbers for all time. I want to get matches for just a single day. The entire day. So to do that we need to include a where clause that checks the AddDateTime attribute.

```
public int CountPartialMatchingTicket(IList<int> numbers, DateTime day) {

}
```

I very new to Linq so please explain the syntax to your solution. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int count = db.Tickets.Where(tk=>tk.AddDateTime == day)
     .Count(tk=>arr.All(n=> tk.TicketNumbers.Any(tn=>tn.Number== n)));
```

You can filter your tickets by the `day` and then continue to your existing query. You might need to check the `properties` of datetime (e.g. `AddDateTime.Day== day.Day && AddDateTime.Month == day.Month && AddDateTime.Year == day.Year`), but that depends on other factors as well. So it's up to you.

Comment: Comparing the DateTime property will also compare the times, which the question did not want. Edit: You edited to add the DateTime.Date property, which won't work for EntityFramework (my guess because of the db reference).

Comment: @mfanto, I mentioned that he might have to check other properties, I left it out because I did not want to clutter the code.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! .Date is not in Linq... so in the end I'm using: Where(tk => tk.PlayDateTime.Year == DateRule.Year && tk.PlayDateTime.Month == DateRule.Month && tk.PlayDateTime.Day == DateRule.Day)

Comment: You can simplify your code by using DbFunctions.TruncateTime(), as found in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can add the filter to the `Count()` method. In order to compare dates for a single day, and ignore time, you'll need to either use the [DateTime.Date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date(v=vs.110).aspx) property, or call [DbFunctions.TruncateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220142(v=vs.113).aspx) for EntityFramework.

```
public int CountPartialMatchingTicket(IList<int> numbers, DateTime day)
{
    var arr = numbers.ToArray();
    int count = db.Tickets.Count(tk => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(tk.AddDateTime) == DbFunctions.TruncateTime(day) && arr.All(n=>     tk.TicketNumbers.Any(tn=>tn.Number== n)));
    return count;
}
```

If you're not using EF, then to compare the [DateTime.Date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date(v=vs.110).aspx) properties:

```
public int CountPartialMatchingTicket(IList<int> numbers, DateTime day)
{
    var arr = numbers.ToArray();
    int count = db.Tickets.Count(tk => tk.AddDateTime.Date == day.Date && arr.All(n=>     tk.TicketNumbers.Any(tn=>tn.Number== n)));
    return count;
}
```

The code reads in English like:

Count all tickets (`db.Tickets.Count(...)`) where the date part of `AddDateTime` matches the date part of `day` AND the `TicketNumber.Number` appears in the array of numbers.

Comment: I'm using EF, though DBFunctions doesn't seem to be defined for me?

Comment: Using the second solution you provided for me I'm getting this error when running the page: The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Comment: You need to add a reference to the namespace System.Data.Entity for DbFunctions.TruncateTime(). If you get undefined references, it's good to look at the MSDN page and see what namespace it's defined in. Or use Resharper, and let it add it for you.

Comment: Gave you a +1 even though I can't get DBFunctions recognized at this time. I do prefer the straight forward solutions with less overhead even if it may be a bit longer to type out.